# What is my error in go?

Tags: go, struct

```
package main
import "fmt"
func main(){
        a:=[]int{1,2,3,4,5}           //slice of int
        b:=[]struct{                  //another slice of struct
                i int
                j string
        }{
                {1,"精"},
                {2 ,"コバや歌詞"},
                {3,"新一"},
                {4,"武士"},
        }
        c:=[]struct{                           //slice of slices
                d []struct
                e []int
        }{
                {a[:],b[:]},
        }


        fmt.Println(a,b,c)
}
```

The errors are:-

> - ./slices.go:16:3: syntax error: unexpected e, expecting {
> - ./slices.go:17:3: syntax error: unexpected {, expecting semicolon or newline or }
> - ./slices.go:18:7: syntax error: unexpected ] at end of statement

Comment: Your error is at `d []struct` - you can't use `struct` as a type without defining the anonymous struct body.

Answer (score 2):

You are creating c struct wrong. It should contain slice of int for first field and slice of struct of b type as second field.

```
    c:=[]struct{                           //slice of slices
            d []int
            e []struct{               //another slice of struct
                i int
                j string
            }
    }{
            {a[:],b[:]},
    }
```

Below code is working

```
package main
import "fmt"
func main(){
     a:=[]int{1,2,3,4,5}           //slice of int
     b:=[]struct{                  //another slice of struct
                i int
                j string
     }{
             {1,"精"},
             {2 ,"コバや歌詞"},
             {3,"新一"},
             {4,"武士"},
     }
     c:=[]struct{                           //slice of slices
            d []int
            e []struct{               //another slice of struct
                i int
                j string
            }
     }{
            {a[:],b[:]},
     }
     fmt.Println(a,b,c)
}
```

[Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/ycqj0MTA5ne)

Comment: maybe create types for the structs so this gets easier to read and less repetitive...

Comment: @TehSphinX That's also an option But may be OP is creating a minimal example of what he wants. So just asking what he is doing wrong.

Comment: Just supposing to show him an additional example. But if you don't want I can add another answer.

Comment: Thanks brother I know we can create separate struct and then create their types. But that's not what he has asked for. Its just why an error is coming in his current code. Your catch is good.

Comment: I'm not so worried about that. If that happens I can still delete the answer and get all points back

Answer (score 1):

In case you wonder how to improve on your code:

```
package main

import "fmt"

type someType struct { // struct
    i int
    j string
}

type composite struct { // struct with slices
    e []int
    d []someType
}

func main() {
    a := []int{1, 2, 3, 4, 5} //slice of int

    b := []someType{ //another slice of struct
        {1, "精"},
        {2, "コバや歌詞"},
        {3, "新一"},
        {4, "武士"},
    }
    c := []composite{ //slice of struct with slices
        {a, b},
    }

    fmt.Println(a, b, c)
}
```

It looks a lot cleaner and while instantiating it is a a lot easier to keep an the overview.

Now it is still readable if you instantiate c with all content:

```
c := []composite{
    {
        e: []int{1, 2, 3, 4, 5},
        d: []someType{
            {1, "精"},
            {2, "コバや歌詞"},
            {3, "新一"},
            {4, "武士"},
        },
    },
}
```

[goplay.space](https://goplay.space/#i4KPwHxYRZS)